# How to make Tkinter buttons commands work

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a class with a button, it runs the command automatically when the gui is constructed (which I don't want it to do) but then doesn't work again after. What am I doing wrong? Built-in commands such as endcommand work as they should.

relevant excerpts (ignore the indent problem at the very beginning)

```
class GuiPart(object):    
def __init__(self, master, queue, endCommand):
    self.queue = queue
    # Set up the GUI
    #tkinter.Button(master, text='Done', command=endCommand).grid(row=6,column=6)
    
    tkinter.Button(text='Update Variables', command=self.updateValues()).grid(row=3)

    Lp_pacingState = tkinter.Label(text="p_pacingState")
    Lp_pacingState.grid(row=1, column=3)
    Tp_pacingState = tkinter.Label(bg="white", relief="ridge",justify="center",width=9)
    Tp_pacingState.grid(row=1, column=4)
    ....
    
    self.textBoxes = {"p_pacingState" : Tp_pacingState, "p_pacingMode" : Tp_pacingMode, 
                 "p_hysteresis" : Tp_hysteresis, "p_hysteresisInterval" : Tp_hysteresisInterval,
                 "p_lowrateInterval" : Tp_lowrateInterval, "p_vPaceAmp" : Tp_vPaceAmp,
                 "p_vPaceWidth" : Tp_vPaceWidth, "p_VRP" : Tp_VRP}

#def updateValues(self,input):
def updateValues(self):
    testInput = ["p_pacingState=3", "garbage=poop", "p_VRP=5"]
    for updates in testInput:
        print("zzzz")
        var = updates.split("=")
        try:
            self.textBoxes[var[0]].config(text = var[1])
        except:
            pass
```

So I get "zzzz" printed 3 times at construction of gui (labels don't update their text though) and the button doesn't work after that.
Also if there's a better way to update boxes please tell me. I get input from a stream in no particular order or relevance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you do this:

```
command=self.updateValues()
```

You are calling the function `self.updateValues` (because of the `()`). The result of that function call is being assigned to the command attribute which is not what you want. You need to remove the `()` so that the `command` attribute gets a reference to the method rather than the result of calling the method.