# Why don't Button clicks do anything?

Tags: python, tkinter

```
from tkinter import *

def plus():
    print('Hello')

root = Tk()

Btn = Button(root, text="Show", command=plus()).pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Note also that `Btn` is not storing what you think it is. If you want to store a  reference to `Btn` don't pack it in the same instruction line as the `Button` constructor call. Just make `Btn.pack()` in the next line.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Tkinter buttons help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4046118/tkinter-buttons-help)

Comment: This is the reason: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5767228/7432

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need for lambda.  Just remove the `()` in `Btn = Button(root, text="Show", command=plus()).pack()`.  This is causing you to call the function before actually pressing the button.

Your button command should look like this:

```
Btn = Button(root, text="Show", command=plus).pack()
```

Comment: how to get text from entry. entry.get() doesn't work

Comment: @user8921550  Can I see some code or something.  I can't guess.

Comment: @user8921550 - edit your answer please, and add the code you posted  as comment before.

Comment: impor....
root=Tk
def click():
     print(E.get())
E = Entry(root)
E.pack()
btn = Button(root, text="click", command=click)
btn.pack()

Comment: @user8921550

`from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

def click():
    print(E.get())

E = Entry(root)
E.pack()
btn = Button(root, text="click", command=click)
btn.pack() 
`

Works perfectly for me.  You just missed the () on Tk.

Comment: @user8921550  Please check your code again.  This is working fine for me.

Comment: I am sorry, it works. I don't know where was the mistake.

Comment: I am sorry. The code is correct

Comment: @user8921550  I think  `root=Tk` was the problem.  That should be   `root=Tk()`

Comment: @user8921550. you may also [want to accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) but only do that if you are satisfied with it and it did actually help.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a lambda. Code:

```
from tkinter import *
def plus(): print('Hello')
root = Tk()
Btn = Button(root, text="Show", command=lambda:plus()).pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Per the requests of the Anti-Lambda league below me, here is a non-lambda version:

```
from tkinter import *
def plus(): print('Hello')
root = Tk()
Btn = Button(root, text="Show", command=plus).pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: It doesn't have to be a lambda, not in this case, and not in many other cases. Usually you need a lambda to pass parameters into the callback.

Comment: Why use lambda?  This is unnecessary (not wrong). Just remove the `()`

Comment: You're right, the lambda wasn't necessary. Alternate version added.